# Stepper motor vibrates, how to reduce vibration

Tags: stepper-motor

**Background**
I have a unipolar stepper motor (which I drive in bi-polar configuration) with a custom constant current driver. This driver can source 15VDC at 1.5 Amps (per coil). My motor is a 20V/0.22 Amp (per coil) stepper motor.  I use micro stepping. The winding resistance is very high (90 ohms per coil).

**Constraints:**
Must keep the same motor. Must keep the same Driver.

**Issue:**
Not all of the time, but at some angles in the shaft the motor vibrates a lot. If you keep moving it, the vibrations will 'go away.'

**Questions:**

1. Is the source of my vibrations caused because my driver is too low of a voltage and I can't source enough current? At best I can source 15V/90 Ohm= 0.16 Amps per coil (126 mH).
2. Why are some micro step angles worse than others? Note, I still have this problem even if I am doing full steps.
3. By some magic, are there any trade secrets to reduce the effective resistance of the motor? Most of the time these motors are holding a position and do not move often and do not need to move quickly.

Thank you

Comment: A stepper motor is always driven with a greater torque than what is strictly required to move the load. Almost all of that extra torque turns into vibration. The reason is that the extra torque accelerates the load to faster than the desired rate of rotation (all within 1 step mind you). The load then hits the next pole and bounces back. Microstepping can help mitigate this, as can running with a lesser torque margin.